# What does explicit *this object parameter offer in C++23?

Tags: c++, this, c++23, explicit-object-parameter

In C++23, [deducing this](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p0847r7.html) is finally added to the standard.

Based on what I've read from the proposal, it opens up a new way of creating mixins, and possible to create recursive lambdas.

But I'm confused if this parameter creates a "copy" without using templates since there is no reference or does the explicit `this` parameter have its own rules of value category?

Since:

```cpp
struct hello {
  void func() {}
};
```

may be the equivalent of:

```cpp
struct hello {
  void func(this hello) {}
};
```

But their type is different because for `&hello::func`, the first one gives `void(hello::*)()`, while the second one gives `void(*)(hello)`

For instance, I have this simple function:

```cpp
struct hello {
  int data;
  void func(this hello self) {
    self.data = 22;
  }
};
```

Doesn't `this` parameter need to be a reference to change the value of `hello` type? Or it basically follows the cv-ref qualifier rules of member function as same as before?

Comment: There's a "motivation" section in the proposal.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Section 4.2.3 of the paper mentions that "by-value `this`" is explicitly allowed and does what you expect. Section 5.4 gives some examples of when you would want to do this.

So in your example, the `self` parameter is modified and then destroyed. The caller's `hello` object is never modified. If you want to modify the caller's object, you need to take `self` by reference:

```
void func(this hello& self) {
  self.data = 22;
}
```